# Why is a simple vector list inside Row not rendering in MatrixForm when passed in as an argument to a user defined function?

Tags: functions, matrix, output-formatting, vector, output

I stripped down a function `makeRuleRow` down to its bare essentials (of irrelevant descriptions) to understand why my vector `list` is not rendering in `MatrixForm` when passed into a `Row` from a user defined function.

Here is the buggy code...

```
SetAttributes[{symbolName,makeRuleRow}, HoldFirst];
symbolName[symbol_Symbol] := SymbolName[Unevaluated[symbol]];
symbolName[symbol_] := 
  Null /; (Message[SymbolName::args, symbolName]; False);
symbolName::usage = 
  "symbolName returns Unevaluated shortened SymbolName.";

makeRuleRow[symbol_?ArrayQ] := {Row[{symbolName, gridrule}], 
   MatrixForm[symbol]};
(list = {1, 2, 3}) // MatrixForm
makeRuleRow[list] (* symbol value renders as a list not MatrixForm *)
```

The buggy output...

[image]

When the results of `makeRuleRow` is manually constructed `list` renders correctly...

```
{Row[{"list", " \[Rule] "}], MatrixForm[list]} (* desired output *)
```

Here is a screenshot of desired output...

[image]

Why is `MatrixForm` not rendering when my `List` is passed in through a user defined function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this definition

`makeRuleRow[symbol_] :=  Row[{symbolName[symbol], MatrixForm[symbol]}, " \[Rule] "];`

Comment: I needed to edit the code. It is correct now (but bug not fixed). Would you mind having a second look at it?

Comment: Try `makeRuleRow[symbol_?ArrayQ] := Row[{symbolName[symbol], " \[Rule] ,", MatrixForm[symbol]}];` Remember to `ClearAll@makeRuleRow` and reevaluate `SetAttributes` first.

Comment: Agree with "Remember to ClearAll@makeRuleRow and reevaluate SetAttributes first". That burned me for a bit.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi thank you it worked and i also did as Paul Comnmentary suggested.

Comment: @PaulCommentary thank you that was the solution (to clear prior definitions)